# How to ignore very first value in a CSV file?

Tags: python, linux, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file (node.csv) with the following data:

```
   0     1     2     3     4
0  12.0  12.5  11.0  10.0  nan
1  15.0  18.0  nan   15.0  17.0
2  20.0  nan   20.0  28.0  27.0

#####This is the output from the following format of data:

sensor_values = {0: {0: 12.0, 1: 15.0, 2: 20.0},
                 1: {0: 12.5, 1: 18.0, 2: np.nan},
                 2: {0: 11.0, 1: np.nan, 2: 20.0},
                 3: {0: 10.0, 1: 150.0, 2: 28.0},
                 4: {0: np.nan, 1: 15.0, 2: 27.0}
                }
```

Of course, the above data is for a clearer picture. The actual data in the file is like the following:

```
,0,1,2,3,4
0,12.0,12.5,11.0,10.0,np.nan
1,15.0,18.0,np.nan,15.0,17.0
2,20.0,np.nan,20.0,28.0,27.0
```

There is absolutely no problem when I try to print the data in the file using Pandas DataFrame as the output looks like the one I wrote above.
The problem arises when I try to load the data into a list using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

#some other code

sensor_values = pd.read_csv('node.csv')

#or using this instead of read_csv -
#sensor_values = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('node.csv')

sensor_values = sensor_values.values.tolist()
```

It always takes in the blank data in the first row first column (" ",.....) of the CSV data file, which I do not want in my script. I only want the relevant data to be taken, but it always seems to start taking the data from the blank value.
How do I prevent this?
Is there any modification that I need to do in the CSV file data  itself?
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Do you want to ignore the whole row? Whole column? You can't ignore just that value. You can replace it with something else.

Comment: Have a look here: (it is very well documented how you skip rows, intial space etc..). https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: It seems you need `sensor_values = pd.read_csv('node.csv', index_col=[0])`.

Comment: @jezrael the solution you provided worked very well. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although credit goes to @jezrael the documentation you are looking for is found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """,0,1,2,3,4
0,12.0,12.5,11.0,10.0,np.nan
1,15.0,18.0,np.nan,15.0,17.0
2,20.0,np.nan,20.0,28.0,27.0
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),index_col=0)
df.to_dict()
```

Output

```
{'0': {0: 12.0, 1: 15.0, 2: 20.0},
 '1': {0: '12.5', 1: '18.0', 2: 'np.nan'},
 '2': {0: '11.0', 1: 'np.nan', 2: '20.0'},
 '3': {0: 10.0, 1: 15.0, 2: 28.0},
 '4': {0: 'np.nan', 1: '17.0', 2: '27.0'}}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the first column is your index. you can use it as the row labels (index) as follow:  `sensor_values = pd.read_csv('node.csv', index_col=[0])`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, you can send a subset of your data to the list, rather than read it in in a different manner:

```
df.loc[:,1:].values.tolist() #.loc slices from column 1 to the end here
```